# How can I join pd dataframes on complex condition?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dataframes. The first one contains `ID` , time marks (can be different dates) and some value. Another contains `ID` and two time intervals. Based on that, I want to deduce class for each entry in the first dataframe. If time between corresponding `start1` and `end1` - 1, between `end1` and `start2` - 2, between `start2` and `end2` - 3, between `end2` and `start1` of next entry - 4.

```
df_values
ID      time              value
1 2022-05-02 20:00:00       1
1 2022-05-02 20:15:00       2
1 2022-05-02 20:30:00       3
1 2022-05-02 21:00:00       1
2 2022-05-02 10:00:00       1
2 2022-05-02 10:15:00       2
2 2022-05-02 10:30:00       3
2 2022-05-02 11:00:00       1


df_times
ID          start1                end1                 start2                  end2 
1  2022-05-02 19:55:00   2022-05-02 20:05:00   2022-05-02 20:20:00     2022-05-02 20:30:00
1  2022-05-02 20:45:00   2022-05-02 20:50:00   2022-05-02 21:10:00     2022-05-02 21:25:00
2  2022-05-02 09:55:00   2022-05-02 10:05:00   2022-05-02 10:20:00     2022-05-02 10:30:00
2  2022-05-02 10:45:00   2022-05-02 10:50:00   2022-05-02 11:10:00     2022-05-02 11:25:00
```

And the desired dataset would be

```
df_values
ID      time              value    class 
1 2022-05-02 20:00:00       1        1
1 2022-05-02 20:15:00       2        2
1 2022-05-02 20:30:00       3        4
1 2022-05-02 21:00:00       1        2
2 2022-05-02 10:00:00       1        1
2 2022-05-02 10:15:00       2        2
2 2022-05-02 10:25:00       3        3
2 2022-05-02 11:00:00       1        2
```

For testing

```
df_values = {'ID' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
             'time' : ['2022-05-02 20:00:00',
                        '2022-05-02 20:15:00',
                        '2022-05-02 20:30:00',
                        '2022-05-02 21:00:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:00:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:15:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:30:00',
                        '2022-05-02 11:00:00'],
             'value' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1]}
df_times = {'ID' : [1, 1, 2, 2],
            'start1' : ['2022-05-02 19:55:00',
                        '2022-05-02 20:45:00',
                        '2022-05-02 09:55:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:45:00'],
            'end1' :   ['2022-05-02 20:05:00',
                        '2022-05-02 20:50:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:05:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:50:00'],
            'start2' : ['2022-05-02 20:20:00',
                        '2022-05-02 21:10:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:20:00',
                        '2022-05-02 11:10:00'],
            'end2' :   ['2022-05-02 20:30:00',
                        '2022-05-02 21:25:00',
                        '2022-05-02 10:30:00',
                        '2022-05-02 11:25:00']}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide the data as a dict? It will help us for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reshape the second dataframe and create the future class value.

```
# future class value
d = {'start1':1, 'end1':2, 'start2':3, 'end2':4}

_df = (
    df_times.set_index('ID')
      .rename(columns=d)
      .rename_axis(columns='class')
      .stack()
      .astype('datetime64[ns]')
      .reset_index(name='time')
)
print(_df)
#     ID  class                time
# 0    1      1 2022-05-02 19:55:00
# 1    1      2 2022-05-02 20:05:00
# 2    1      3 2022-05-02 20:20:00
# 3    1      4 2022-05-02 20:30:00
# 4    1      1 2022-05-02 20:45:00
# 5    1      2 2022-05-02 20:50:00
# ...
```

Then use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

```
# need datetime data type
df_values['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_values['time'])

res = pd.merge_asof(
    df_values.sort_values('time'),
    _df.sort_values('time'),
    by='ID', on='time', 
    direction='backward'
)
print(res)
#    ID                time  value  class
# 0   2 2022-05-02 10:00:00      1      1
# 1   2 2022-05-02 10:15:00      2      2
# 2   2 2022-05-02 10:30:00      3      4
# 3   2 2022-05-02 11:00:00      1      2
# 4   1 2022-05-02 20:00:00      1      1
# 5   1 2022-05-02 20:15:00      2      2
# 6   1 2022-05-02 20:30:00      3      4
# 7   1 2022-05-02 21:00:00      1      2
```

Note: you may want to `sort_values` the `res`